# Rails 5 - view changes using Audited gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, acts-as-audited

In my app that I build to learn RoR, I want to add change tracking and use the Audited gem for that. While it is clear how to add it to my models, how can I see the changes?

I would want to add a link / button on each page for the different objects / classes / models that opens a view with the audit log. i.e. listing all changes (date/time, field, old value, new value, by user) sorted by the date/time of the change.

Can't find any documentation for it. All help to get started appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was needed exact feature when I was working with Papertrail Gem few months back. I modified my code to work for audited gem. I hope below haml code will give you really nice start.

```
%table.table.table-hover
  %thead
    %tr
      %th Type
      %th When
      %th Who
      %th What Changed
    - model.audits.order(:created_at).each do |audit|
      %tr
        %td= audit.action
        %td= audit.created_at
        %td= audit.user.name
        %td
          - audit.audited_changes.each do |k, v|
            %b= k.titleize
            from
            %b= "'#{v[0]}'"
            to
            %b= "'#{v[1]}'"
            %br
```

The code is self explanatory If you go through https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited

Explanation for audited_changes:
For audited_changes we have hash like `audit.audited_changes # => {"name"=>["Steve", "Ryan"]}`. That means you have hash with string as a key and array with two values. first value is before updation and second is after updation.

Comment: Tx Dinesh - will take a look at it early this week. Then let you know.

Comment: Pay attention: audited_changes value could be an array OR string!

- audit.audited_changes.each do |k, v|
   %b= k.titlesize
   - if v.class == Array
     from
                             = "'#{v[0]}'"
                              to
                              =# "'#{v[1]}'"
                            - else
                              = "'#{v}'"
                            %br

Comment: Why do I get `undefined method 'audits'`? I'm running Ruby 2.5.1, Rails 5.2.0, and Audited 4.8.0. I copied the code then replace `model` with my modal name/class.

Comment: How did you resolve the problem you encountered ? @DavidAngulo

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @[dnsh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3079520/dnsh), i changed his code and added else:

```
%table.table.table-hover
  %thead
    %tr
      %th Type
      %th When
      %th Who
      %th What Changed
    - model.audits.order(:created_at).each do |audit|
      %tr
        %td= audit.action
        %td= audit.created_at
        %td= audit.user.name
        %td
          - audit.audited_changes.each do |k, v|
            %b= k.titleize
            - if v.class == Array # if updated
              from
              %b= "'#{v[0]}'"
              to
              %b= "'#{v[1]}'"
              %br
            - else # if created
              = v
```

Comment: I am not sure why this answer was upvoted, but it currently doesn't work as the audits method throws up an undefined error message
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27353017/gem-audited-activerecord-4-0-gives-undefined-method-audits